# How can Substrate documentation best support the community?

Tags: discussion

The docs.substrate.io site—also known as the Developer Hub docs site—is undergoing some major renovation and refactoring. The goal of the changes is to provide a more narrative structure to the content, hopefully making it both more inviting and easier to navigate.
At a high level, the content has been reorganized into the following main sections:

**Docs**:

- Fundamentals
- Install
- Build
- Test

**Tutorials**:

- Get started
- Work with pallets
- Develop smart contracts

**Reference**:

- Glossary
- Command-line tools
- Rust API

You can get a sneak peak at the new site by checking out the URL:
https://substrate-docs-md.netlify.app/quick-start/

and using this password:
substr@te

Feel free to tag me or reply to this post if you want to offer comments and suggestions. This is still a work in progress and there are some rough edges, but it would be great to get more eyes on the direction it’s going and to get your feedback on where it should go next…

We want to provide documentation that helps builders build!

Answer (score 1):

Something I would like to see more are more usage examples. Like more code examples/sample code, also more references to real world implementations, like a link to some github repo after a scenario has been described. For example:
Here is try-runtime: https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/tools/use-try-runtime/

If there could be some links to real world implementations of try-runtime so developers can get a better grip of how "production" systems use this.

Comment: Sometimes I find that greping through how others have done it is very useful to see what the 'standard' way of doing it is. One repo to grep them all:  http://github.com/gilescope/parachains

Comment: sweet, I have a bash script that does this, been using github code search for the most